# Equivalence of two definitions of ergodicity

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

Suppose $\phi = \{\phi_{t}\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is a flow on a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$. Suppose $\mu$ is stationary with respect to $\phi$, that is, $\mu(A) = \mu(\phi_{t}^{-1}(A))$ holds for every $A \in \mathcal{F}$ and $t \in \mathbb{R}$. We say that $\phi$ is ergodic if every measurable set $F \in \mathcal{F}$ satisfying $\phi_{t}(F) = F$ has either probability $\mu(F) = 0$ or $\mu(F) =1$.

I know that this definition implies the following result: $\phi$ is ergodic iff the only functions $f \in L^{2}(\Omega,d\mu)$ satisfying $f\circ \phi_{t} = f$ are the constant functions.

I want to prove the following: $\phi$ is ergodic if, and only if for every $f \in L^{1}(\Omega,d\mu)$ the time average:
$$\bar{f}(x) := \lim_{T\to \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^{T}(f\circ\phi_{t})(x)dt \tag{1}\label{1}$$
exists and is a constant $\bar{f}$, given by the expectation:
$$\bar{f} = \int f(x)d\mu(x). \tag{2}\label{2}$$

I already proved one direction. If $f \in L^{1}(\Omega,d\mu)$, by Birkhoff Ergodic Theorem the time average limit (\ref{1}) exists and equals its expectation. In particular, this condition implies $\bar{f}\circ \phi_{t} = \bar{f}$. Hence, if $\phi$ is ergodic, because $L^{1}(\Omega,d\mu) \subset L^{2}(\Omega,d\mu)$ we get $\bar{f}(x) = \bar{f}$ is a constant and equals its expectation.

However, I am stuck at proving the converse, that is, if the time average $\bar{f}(x)$ in (\ref{1}) exists, and is a constant given by (\ref{2}), then $\phi$ is ergodic. Any help is welcome!

Comment: I may be missing something, but $(\Omega, \mathcal{F},\mu)$ is a probability space, so, we have $L^{2}(\Omega,d\mu) \subset L^{1}(\Omega,d\mu)$ , not $L^{1}(\Omega,d\mu) \subset L^{2}(\Omega,d\mu)$.

Comment: Oh, Yes. My bad. So, my argument for the first part of the proof remains valid, with a minor modification: take $f$ to be $L^{2}$ instead of $L^{1}$.

Comment: For the first part of the proof, you need to take $f\in L^1$. You can not simply restrict yourself to $f\in L^2$.